# Minimum Vb.net Form size

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can we shrink the width of form size less than 132 and height less than 38 Please help me about it.

Here is the code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To meWidth
    If (Me.Width > 0) Then
        Me.Width = Me.Width - 20
        Me.Refresh()
        For FadeCount = 40 To 40 Step 20
            Me.Opacity = FadeCount / 100
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
        Next
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: If you want to shrink the form less than the size that you mentioned, try setting the FormForderStyle to FixedSingle at some point.

Comment: You cannot make a window smaller than the size of the title bar.  It shouldn't matter much, if you are doing it right then Opacity is so low by the time the window shrinks to that size that isn't visible anymore.  Well, assuming you'll write that For loop properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your minimun form size with the property `Form.MinimumSize`. Check the [MSDN Documentation about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize.aspx).

Basically:

> This property enables you to limit the size of a form to a specified minimum size. You can use this feature to prevent a user from sizing a window to an undesirable size. If this property is set to a Size object that is 0 in height and 0 in width, the form will have no minimum size beyond the limits set by Windows.

Comment: Can we make form icon(that is present with the text of form) click able. I set icon to another pic of my system now i want to click icon and it will go another place. Is this possible please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider [marking the answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/208536) and upvoting if it helped you. And about the icon clicking, please create another question.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find this answer anywhere and I would like to share my solution:

```
Me.Text = ""
Me.ControlBox = False
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
Me.MinimumSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1, 1) 'HERE IS MY FIX
Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 23)
```

By not allowing the `MinimumSize` property to remain at (0,0) by default, it seems to have cleared this bug up for me.

Answer (score 0):

U can Control Minimum Size : Example

```
    Dim MinWidth As Integer = 396
    Dim MinHeigh As Integer = 369

    If Me.Width <= MinWidth Then
        Me.Width = MinWidth
    End If


    If Me.Height <= MinHeigh Then
        Me.Height = MinHeigh
    End If
```